# Method does not have implementation in servicestack redis

Tags: c#, servicestack.redis

I'm getting the following message after upgrade to new version of Servicestack.redis (our code dosen't call directly to redis native client)
Method "Migrate" in type "ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient" from assembly "ServiceStack.Redis, Version=4.0.33.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" does not have an implementation.

Any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TypeLoadException` and `MethodMissingException` errors are indicative of using dirty dlls from using older versions of ServiceStack together.

Make sure that all NuGet packages are updated, if the issues persist delete the NuGet `/packages` folder and download the NuGet packages again, checking to make sure that only it only references ServiceStack packages with the **same version number**, updating any projects that reference any old NuGet package versions.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you updated [ServiceStact](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack) which have [IRedisNativeClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/IRedisNativeClient.cs) interface with `Migrate` method and using older version of [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) which implements IRedisNativeClient interface in [RedisNativeClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisNativeClient.cs). As you can see in github RedisNativeClient implements required method. So try to update ServiceStack.Redis.